# How to transfer data from one Screen to another in android?

Tags: android, string, transfer

I am trying to transfer data from one page to another but some problem is coming. below is the code.its force closing the app after i am pressing the second page button

Here my first program:

```
package com.life.insurance;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
/*import android.view.Menu;*/
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class LifeInsuranceActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
/*    private static final int MENU_STARS = 1;
    private static final int MENU_REFRESH = 2;*/
  Context mCtx;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button submit =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        submit.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.button1:
             mCtx = this;

             String intext = new String();
             intext=((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1)).getText().toString(); 

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(mCtx, MenuSelection.class); 
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle(1);
                bundle.putString("ganna", intext);
                myIntent.putExtras(bundle);

                /*Start Activity*/
                mCtx.startActivity(myIntent);

                /*Start ActivityForResult*/
                ((Activity)mCtx).startActivityForResult(myIntent, 2);

            setContentView(R.layout.menuselection);
            break;      
        }
    }
}
```

This is my second Activity

```
package com.life.insurance;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MenuSelection  extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
     String ot;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.menuselection);
        Button search =(Button)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
        search.setOnClickListener(this);
        Bundle extras = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        ot =extras.getString("ganna").toString();
        final  TextView r =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt1);
        r.setText(ot);

    }

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()){
    case R.id.imageButton1:


        break;

    }
  }

}
```

please help me to do this

Comment: Is there a logcat stacktrace and can you post it?

Comment: Could you post any errors that show up in Logcat? Also did you remember to declare your second activity in the androidmanifest file?

Comment: We need the logcat output, can you edit the post with the output?

Answer (score 3):

It's tough to answer without a logcat dump, but I think there are a few things to check. First, sending a String should be straight forward:

```
intent.putExtra("key", "value");
```

If you want to send complex objects or bundles, you can do that but I am sticking to your problem of sending and reading a String.

```
getIntent().getStringExtra("key")
```

I think using Bundle, in your case, isn't necessary.

Secondly, you are calling startActivity and startActivityForResult. Call one or the other. Since you are looking for a response, you probably want to use the latter.

Finally, make sure you've added your second activity to your manifest as suggested below. You also want to use the contexts of your Activity, not of the buttons when starting subsequent activities.

There seems to be several issues here which could be causing a crash.